# JavaFX - Open a Scene from another class event in main method

Tags: java, javafx

I want to Open a Scene from another class on main class
I tried every solution here but not working with me i don't know why
I want to open the scene from the button called stock
I erased the code caused the error when i was trying and i put onley the soft code i am going to use 
This is main class:

```
public class Dokan extends Application{
@Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {           
        Button stock = new Button ("المخزن");        
        GridPane root= new GridPane();
        ObservableList list=root.getChildren();
        list.add(stock);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);
        Scene scene=new Scene(root, 800, 600);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("dokan/css/style.css");
        stage.setTitle("لوحة التحكم");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
        Stage stockS = new Stage();
        stock.setOnAction( e->{
        stockS.show();
        });
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

this is the class i want to open from main class

```
public class Stock extends Application {
@Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
            Text test= new Text("hello from stock");
    GridPane rootstock=new GridPane();
    ObservableList list= rootstock.getChildren();
    list.add(test);
Scene scene = new Scene(rootstock, 800, 600);
}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: You should always treat the `Application` class as entry point instead of adding compicated logic to it. If you move the logic for creating the scenes to seperate classes, it becomes much simpler to reuse the classes. (Only a single `Application` can be launched and if you create a new `Application` instance for every scene, you need to pass a stage to the `start` method of the second app and somehow deal with the fact that lifecycle methods like `init` and `stop` are not called for the second application instance.)

Comment: thanks so much my problem solved